# Test if rows in a column of many dfs line up

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to confirm that all loaded data sets line up. I used this code to load 160+ dfs.

```
temp<- list.files(pattern="*.txt")

for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i],
                                                 header=TRUE,
                                                 skip=50,
                                                 fill=TRUE,
                                                 na.strings= "N/A",
                                                 sep="\t",
                                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

The name of the df corresponds to the name of the file loaded via list.files.

There are 13 columns in each df, first column is class character, the other 12 to the right are just numbers.

first master

```
structure(list(Variable = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("", "A", 
"B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "J"), class = "factor"), 
X1 = c(0.625443367, NA, 0.975828895, 0.272109249, NA, 0.60981303, 
0.740266164, 0.748793558, 0.393551957, 0.700720729, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.60631742, 0.878735054, 0.689660004), X5 = c(0.025719335, 
NA, 0.285526204, 0.765384454, NA, 0.309337488, 0.723688501, 
0.072082882, 0.302196899, 0.372761724, NA, NA, NA, 0.790174238, 
0.002225558, 0.223989171), X10 = c(0.26885441, NA, 0.39713263, 
0.913498581, NA, 0.314770795, 0.218497868, 0.3676068, 0.376874153, 
0.297697154, NA, NA, NA, 0.297835764, 0.208253053, 0.519716555
), X20 = c(0.410364897, NA, 0.053464372, 0.038994949, NA, 
0.507067813, 0.5960247, 0.314273854, 0.628876194, 0.198480138, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.524002845, 0.592291169, 0.821217561), X25 = c(0.344474094, 
NA, 0.219674393, 0.47614914, NA, 0.771914616, 0.967852724, 
0.32422822, 0.234324065, 0.298566916, NA, NA, NA, 0.477679941, 
0.693787752, 0.622578002), X30 = c(0.084594429, NA, 0.765283085, 
0.64814448, NA, 0.576817659, 0.133505819, 0.049836577, 0.991388257, 
0.925608219, NA, NA, NA, 0.951692117, 0.787417848, 0.111758489
), X40 = c(0.466207213, NA, 0.127350859, 0.152163267, NA, 
0.232783401, 0.720905124, 0.258173477, 0.190757375, 0.422502772, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.505852543, 0.649902446, 0.478459633), X60 = c(0.796558464, 
NA, 0.318127005, 0.926698695, NA, 0.71276073, 0.308905911, 
0.223667445, 0.973655845, 0.206662152, NA, NA, NA, 0.501497143, 
0.432936032, 0.9384412), X70 = c(0.440348619, NA, 0.062959618, 
0.349952146, NA, 0.494978772, 0.32985092, 0.261574102, 0.077362987, 
0.006246765, NA, NA, NA, 0.771499936, 0.195204747, 0.463747804
), X75 = c(0.514698758, NA, 0.126075423, 0.269197828, NA, 
0.55381458, 0.068921312, 0.890791926, 0.484704932, 0.068021153, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.054235262, 0.252056176, 0.824778366), X80 = c(0.199104477, 
NA, 0.659367187, 0.829178346, NA, 0.668647488, 0.966607154, 
0.288800878, 0.563024474, 0.795475571, NA, NA, NA, 0.306623595, 
0.5060437, 0.609508687), X90 = c(0.470471037, NA, 0.016390655, 
0.12824423, NA, 0.15501053, 0.49744774, 0.587190593, 0.03860296, 
0.909975706, NA, NA, NA, 0.478775103, 0.466123148, 0.954408974
), X100 = c(0.452628911, NA, 0.543662895, 0.897387563, NA, 
0.852554978, 0.008392849, 0.727833622, 0.692729898, 0.327026377, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.171860186, 0.171295653, 0.711265826)), .Names = c("Variable", 
"X1", "X5", "X10", "X20", "X25", "X30", "X40", "X60", "X70", 
"X75", "X80", "X90", "X100"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
c-16L))
```

second + every other data frame

```
structure(list(Variable = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("", "A", 
"B", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "J"), class = "factor"), 
X1 = c(0.71772223, NA, 0.445279447, 0.328470358, NA, 0.214795692, 
0.470536908, 0.82732089, 0.464811155, 0.52400864, NA, NA, 
NA, 0.858809889, 0.055051877, 0.499075195), X5 = c(0.496093039, 
NA, 0.405563046, 0.458302396, NA, 0.742840768, 0.192381432, 
0.48193671, 0.284869279, 0.1783585, NA, NA, NA, 0.295773915, 
0.092254844, 0.930647971), X10 = c(0.048447731, NA, 0.974280138, 
0.153448343, NA, 0.826966581, 0.133392525, 0.934463759, 0.701416491, 
0.137353566, NA, NA, NA, 0.52370726, 0.371699579, 0.393444667
), X20 = c(0.232144042, NA, 0.069088242, 0.163514017, NA, 
0.901702062, 0.579277573, 0.557358979, 0.697870038, 0.177942824, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.36971146, 0.182820789, 0.454973585), X25 = c(0.88175934, 
NA, 0.553180662, 0.556749037, NA, 0.184943228, 0.723875496, 
0.833417008, 0.952976588, 0.311258815, NA, NA, NA, 0.064346785, 
0.881648923, 0.497046119), X30 = c(0.745848598, NA, 0.926385172, 
0.613611568, NA, 0.362829401, 0.410915192, 0.090760519, 0.795099045, 
0.100925491, NA, NA, NA, 0.183288884, 0.837146519, 0.294641301
), X40 = c(0.110017321, NA, 0.142722733, 0.919954172, NA, 
0.303358785, 0.177350673, 0.758699705, 0.024830843, 0.973013422, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.678465189, 0.202803024, 0.363498489), X60 = c(0.038027421, 
NA, 0.128757622, 0.290252079, NA, 0.347772735, 0.319189776, 
0.033640467, 0.168359937, 0.678375815, NA, NA, NA, 0.910821265, 
0.676928769, 0.020390321), X70 = c(0.164725423, NA, 0.076708887, 
0.426349446, NA, 0.111726941, 0.885202911, 0.208038512, 0.483489353, 
0.63842772, NA, NA, NA, 0.563524016, 0.592008359, 0.902034255
), X75 = c(0.752526205, NA, 0.098905773, 0.698064546, NA, 
0.475803147, 0.608763409, 0.734027279, 0.281559317, 0.04209597, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.402657881, 0.93614701, 0.391491961), X80 = c(0.305369825, 
NA, 0.921383845, 0.897702227, NA, 0.888330486, 0.548283328, 
0.33654243, 0.864674852, 0.162143087, NA, NA, NA, 0.178685183, 
0.614535137, 0.390157716), X90 = c(0.032753318, NA, 0.068951568, 
0.432669498, NA, 0.089337049, 0.906531493, 0.150399021, 0.984217523, 
0.286168266, NA, NA, NA, 0.582072291, 0.682639084, 0.695373804
), X100 = c(0.479303334, NA, 0.392449509, 0.126543887, NA, 
0.631454516, 0.195057206, 0.780936135, 0.557763263, 0.091113557, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.191267017, 0.818748811, 0.820413052)), .Names = c("Variable", 
"X1", "X5", "X10", "X20", "X25", "X30", "X40", "X60", "X70", 
"X75", "X80", "X90", "X100"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Essentially, I want to guarantee that the content and order of the Variable column are identical. (Note the two J on the bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list of your data frames. If you are `assigning` directly into the environment and `temp` holds the names then you can extract this list out of the environment with

```
dfs<-mget(unlist(temp))
```

Now you can check that the first column of each is the same

```
master<-dfs[[1]][,1]
all(unlist(lapply(dfs,function(df) all(master==df[,1]))))
```

This produces a list of checks of each against the first data frame and then makes sure they are all true.

But instead of `assigning` into the environment as you read, consider loading into a list instead. Then you can do `as.environment` to your list and `attach` if desired.

Comment: That's not working. temp is a vector. like c("data_file-1900.txt", "data_file-1901.txt", ...) But the dfs loaded are also named the corresponding file name. Data frame one named data_file-1900.txt

Comment: Yes, I missed that you were assigning each data frame to a name in the environment. Consider loading into a list instead. Then you can do `as.environment` to your list and `attach` if desired.